# Is there a way to copy a data structure from the 'Variables' window in the debugger?

Tags: phpstorm

When debugging in PhpStorm, I am aware that you can right click on a variable in the 'Variables' pane, and select the context menu item 'Copy Value'. Is there a way to copy a data structure, such as an array or object?

```
$_GET = {array} [1]
    someVariable = "Hello this is a value, and it happens to be a string"
    anotherVar   = "What is this string"
```

If i right-click on 'someVariable' and select 'Copy Value', I will have the string on my clipboard.

If I right click on the line with the array and select 'Copy Value', I get '[1]' on my clipboard.

What I would really like is when I right click and 'Copy Value' on the array to have something like this on my clipboard:

```
'[ 'someVariable' = 'Hello this is a value, and it happens to be a string', 'anotherVar' = 'What is this string ]'
```

Any ideas, or does someone need to make this plugin? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently not possible.

Please watch/vote this ticket to get notified on progress: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-5693

Comment: Yes, it is possible, [read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394659/is-there-a-way-to-copy-a-data-structure-from-the-variables-window-in-the-debug/28487879#28487879).

Answer (score 17):

Starting with PhpStorm version 9.0.0 (released July 8, 2015):

- When debugging in PhpStorm, right click on a variable in the 'Variables' pane, and select the context menu item 'Copy Value As...' to copy the variable as result of one of **[print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)**, **[var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)** or **[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)**.

With PhpStorm <9.0.0, I was using the following trick (PhpStorm 8.0.2):

- When debugging in PhpStorm, right click on a variable in the 'Variables' pane, and select the context menu item 'Evaluate Expression...'.
- The **Evaluate Expression** is opened with your variable in the "Expression:" field. In your case `$_GET`
- In the "Expression:" wrap your variable with the **[var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)** function. In your case: `var_export($_GET,1)`. (The second parameter is set to 1 to return the variable representation instead of outputting it)
- Click the "Evaluate" button to see the result on the "Result:" text area.
- Right click on your result and select "Copy Value" or use copy shortcut
- Enjoy! (If you prefer a different output you can use other functions as well, for example `print_r($_GET,1)`)

Comment: The whole procedure works for me so far, except that when i copy the result of the expression i always copy "can not get property". Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Okay, i managed to solve it. It didn't work with xdebug 2.2.5, so i updated to 2.3.2 and now it works!